# How to get the correct date and time even if the phone date time is wrong?

Tags: ios, nsdate

I want to get the current date and time in this format `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`.I kow I can get this in this way

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"date = %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:today]);
```

But I want to know whether does it returns a wrong date and time if the phone date and time is wrong? If so how cn I get the correct date and time even if the phone date and time is wrong?

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try it? Set your device's time to the wrong time and see what you get.

Comment: Yeas I cahnged the time and checked. It gets the phone time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't know "it returns a wrong date and time if the phone date and time is wrong" and can't "get the correct date and time even if the phone date and time is wrong" in local.

You have to use an online timer for checking, like:
http://www.timeanddate.com/